# Report on folder and sub folder permissions along with all files

Tags: excel, powershell, permissions, report

Currently have this script that will report on permissions within the top folder and child folders. I need it to also report on all files as well. I already have the Export-Excel module installed so that it can export out to an excel file.

```bash
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "E:\TEMP\" -Recurse -Force
$Output = @()
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
        $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
        $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties 
    } 
} 
$Output | Export-Excel E:\TEMP\Report.xlsx -TableName Permissions -AutoSize
```

Much appreciated in advance for any help ppl can give.

Comment: What’s the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the $FolderPath variable using the "-Directory" switch you're only going to get folders/directories in the variable.

You either need to remove that switch or make a whole other copy of the code that replaces line 1 with a new variable such as $Filepath

$Filepath = Get-ChildItem -File -Path "E:\TEMP" -Recurse -Force

and then itterate through each file ACL object just like you did for the folders

### UPDATE

I just tested it with the "-Directory" switch removed and it retern ACL objects for both files and folders.